# Example with まじかる

Tags: grammar, classical-japanese

I've tried to find an example of use of まじかる (打消推量の助動詞「まじ」の連体形). However, no matter how much I search, I can't find any sentence from any real text with まじかる.

The dictionaries I have consulted do not offer any examples either

https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%98%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B

and I don't have at my disposal any physical dictionary in which I could perhaps find examples.

Could you please help me find an example sentence with まじかる belonging to a real text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search classical Japanese in the following government-funded library.

- [次世代デジタルライブラリー](https://lab.ndl.go.jp/dl/)

Just picking a few:

> 住む**まじかる**山里
>
> ([平田盛胤, 国語学：日本文典](https://lab.ndl.go.jp/dl/book/863766?keyword=%E3%81%BE%E3%81%98%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B&page=131)）

> ひとたびは逢ひてふたたび見**まじかる**
> 人にものいふ朝の寂しさ
>
> ([片口安之助, 寂しき路](https://lab.ndl.go.jp/dl/book/915580?keyword=%E3%81%BE%E3%81%98%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B&page=11))

> かくて歌も情の物に感ずるよりよみ出づるわざなれば、いにしへ今高きみじかき、かはりはある**まじかる**べきことわりながらも
>
> ([藤村作 近世論文集](https://lab.ndl.go.jp/dl/book/1106657?keyword=%E3%81%BE%E3%81%98%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B&page=53))

Note that there are more hits for すさまじかる, which is not an instance of the auxiliary verb まじ.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link and the examples. Your answer has been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In classical Japanese the usage is more restricted, since according to 'A Handbook of Classical Japanese', John Timothy Wixted, the 連体形 of the かり活用 form is only used with following suffixes, one exception being おおし, おおかる can modify nouns directly. The normal 連体形 of まじ is thus まじき or まじい; from 枕草子, the name of a section, 打ち解くまじきもの, 'Things one cannot be inattentive about', 打ち解く 'to be negligent about, to be inattentive about'.

Compare this with, for example, 其願はむなしかるべくは, 'if that desire is pointless' (平家物語).